# What causes "object is not an instance of declaring class"?

Tags: java, reflection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do I get “object is not an instance of declaring class” when invoking a method using reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7202988/why-do-i-get-object-is-not-an-instance-of-declaring-class-when-invoking-a-meth)

When I run the code below, why does it throw this error?

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.Test.main(Test.java:10)
```

Here's my main class:

```
    package com;
    public class TestMain {
        private String strName = "abcdefg...";

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        private void display(){
            System.out.println(strName);
        }
    }
```

And my test class:

```
    package com;
    import java.lang.reflect.Method;
    public class Test {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Class<TestMain> tm = null; 
            try{
                tm= TestMain.class;
                Method m1 =tm.getDeclaredMethod("display"); 
                m1.setAccessible(true);
                m1.invoke(tm);
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

This is my modified code, thank you:

```
package com;
    import java.lang.reflect.Method;
    public class Test {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            TestMain tm =new TestMain(); 
            try{
                Method m1 = tm.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("display"); 
                m1.setAccessible(true);
                m1.invoke(tm);
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need an instance, not the class:

```
TestMain object = // get TestMain object here
m1.invoke(object);
```

Or if you mean a static method, supply null as first parameter:

```
m1.invoke(null);
```

Answer (score 1):

`m1` needs to be invoked on an instance of the `TestMain` class, not on the class itself (i.e. on an object created by `new TestMain()`).