# Reflection in java with 2D arrays

Tags: java, arrays, reflection

How to define 2-dim array in reflection?

```
int[][] x={ {1,1,2},{1,1,2},{3,3,3}};
Class<?> c= Class.forName("Ex2");
Class nameClassArr = Class.forName("[[I");
Method methodcall1= c.getDeclaredMethod("biggestRect", nameClassArr );
Object invoke = methodcall1.invoke(c, x);
```

In this way I get warning in compilation:

```
javac testEx2.java
testEx2.java:113: warning: non-varargs call of varargs method with inexact argument type for last parameter;
                Object invoke = methodcall1.invoke(c, x);
                                                      ^
  cast to Object for a varargs call
  cast to Object[] for a non-varargs call and to suppress this warning
1 warning
```

And error in running:

```
java testEx2
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Ex2.biggestRect([[I)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Unknown Source)
        at testEx2.main(testEx2.java:112)
```

In class Ex2 I have a function "biggestRect" that her arguments is 2-dim array

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: This should work. Give exception details, for example you method may be private

Comment: I have to ask:  why do you want to do this?  Reflection can do a lot of things and get at the root of a lot of places, but given that arrays themselves are a special kind of object, I never saw much value in reflecting on them since it was easier to just invoke the array I wanted.  Could you explain your motivation here?

Comment: GBlodgett , jaudo I Edit my questions and add the warning and the error. thanks. @Makoto  I have to check assignments for students. To the assignments have the same class name(Ex2.java),I do a code that compile and run the assignments.but sometimes the function dont exist so the test fail when i call to function.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getting the name of the class for int[][] with the string just pass the class object there

```
Method methodcall1= c.getDeclaredMethod("biggestRect", int[][].class );
```

Also see here [Why do I get "object is not an instance of declaring class" when invoking a method using reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7202988/why-do-i-get-object-is-not-an-instance-of-declaring-class-when-invoking-a-meth), the first parameter of the call

```
methodcall1.invoke(c, x);
```

should be the object instance, not the class object

Comment: I would be happy if you will see the error,I Edit my question and add the error.
 I get another error from this question. And what value can I add to invoke?

Comment: Like I said, remove the Class.forName("[[I"), and use the int[][].class directly. Then instead of methodcall1.invoke(c, x); where c is a Class object do methodcall1.invoke(new Ex2(), x);